# Blender baking is absolutely black after exporting and re-importing mesh

Tags: mesh, import, texture-baking, baking

I have a mesh that I modify through scaling and then bake, the result looking like:

[image]

I then exported it as an obj and re-imported it. But when I try to bake it again I get:

[image]

The meshes should be identical. So I am not sure what could be causing the second to be rendered black.

It also takes no time to "Bake" the baking bar appears for half a second showing 0% and then disapears. As if blender considers that it's not worth baking the object.

Edit:
Working: [image]

Not working: [image]

Comment: Please edited your question and add the .blend(s): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/